# Pass data to new page and call js function passing as a parameter the sent data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, window.open

My goal is to open a new page and append some data in a specific div of that page with javascript using some data sent by the first page.

***The code is quite staightforward but i will also try to explain what it's doing:***

I tried to achieve that by calling a js function `show_img(x)` when the user clicks on a div, passing to it the parameter specified on that div (i.e. "art12") which i want to pass to the next page. In show_img() i open a new window with `window.open()` and then i call a function `fill_page()` that exists in that window passing to it as a parameter ("art12"). In `fill_page(x)` i want to append some data to a specific div of the opened page which data i will retrieve using ajax and passing as data "art12". I tried to just append data to that div in the functon that i called in the first page `show_img(x)` without calling a function of the opened page but nothing is appended.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

**index.php**

```
<div class="img_mid" onclick="show_img('art11');">
</div>
<div class="img_mid" onclick="show_img('art12');">
</div>
<div class="img_mid" onclick="show_img('art13');">
</div>
```

**show_image.js**

```
function show_img(x)
{
   var temp = window.open("img_page.php","_self");
   $(temp.document).load(function() 
   {
      fill_page(x); //functon in js file that is declared in img_page.php
   });
}
```

**img_page.php** looks something like this and fill_page(x) functon is inside fill.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fill.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
     <header>
         content
         content
     </header>
     <div id="div_to_append_content_to">

     </div>
 </body>
```

**fill.js**

```
function fill_page(x)
{
   //will use x to to get content from database using ajax
   var textToInsert = [];
   textToInsert[0] = 'content';
   textToInsert[1] = 'more content';
   textToInsert[2] = 'some more content';
   $("#div_to_append_content_to").append(textToInsert.join(''));
}
```

Comment: Easiest way seems to be using a GET param, i.e. img_page.php?image=bla and then parse that in your php script

Comment: That solved it, thank you.